# Xcode signal SIGABRT error

Tags: ios, xcode

I am receiving the error below

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

I have a button "Home" in my second view controller that goes  back to the initial view controller and it works fine provided that I do not keep pressing the "Home" button in a cycle for more than 15 times.

Comment: Put an exceptional break point and c where is the exact crash happend

Comment: provide the stack trace or the crash logs